# Opening app after applicationWillTerminate in a preferred state when opening from another app?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

My app is currently able to be opened from another app. All info that is being passed from other app is being read in `application(application: UIApplication, openURL url...` and the app state will be retained as desired.

Upon first launch the `appDelegate` first opens `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, however if the user double clicks the home button and terminate the app by sliding up the `applicationWillTerminate` is called and the app is killed.

When launching my app from another app after it has been killed, the app is first calling `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and then calls the `application(application: UIApplication, openURL url...`

How can I ensure that the app knows which url is being passed from within the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method? Is there a way to ascertain that beforehand instead of within `application(application: UIApplication, openURL url...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the URL should be available in the `launchOptions` dictionary *if* the app was launched via a URL from another application:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let url = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.url] as? NSURL

}
```

Check the `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` documentation if you're interested in everything that the launchOptions dictionary might contain (it links to all the keys you can use):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application